# Pipeline job failure after docker restart

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm totally new to Jenkins.

Pipeline job is getting failed after docker restart.

I had a Jenkins base version of '2.89.4'. I upgraded it to '2.222.1'. To create pipeline job, installed/upgraded all the required dependencies. Created pipeline job(Stage job is a maven project) is getting passed. But after I restart my docker container, job is failing with errors mentioned below. Pipeline job is a parameterized project.

Jenkins is hosted on a docker container
OS version is SLES11 SP1
Java version - java-8-openjdk-amd64

**Command used to restart docker container**

```
docker restart cd01dd93f17d
```

Error:

```
Started by user XYZ
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/PIIII
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableField.isAccessible()Z
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:920)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$0(RiverWriter.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:237)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:552)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:529)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:516)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:440)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Pipeline script(Groovy):

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
node {

    stage ('3D_Docker_IPConfiguration'){
            build job: '3D_Docker_IPConfiguration', propagate: false,  parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'CollectorIP', value: CollectorIP_1 ]]
    }
}
```

**List of plugins installed/used for pipeline job**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**For reference please find the screenshots of the passed job before restart and failed job after restart**
[image: Build History]

[image: Pass result before docker restart]

[image: Fail result before docker restart]

Its a show stopper for me. Spent more than 4 days to resolve but couldn't do it. Please help me in resolving this issue at the earliest.

For any further details please let me know.

Thanks for the help in advance:)

Comment: Have you checked if Jenkins threw some errors while starting up? Maybe some Plugin hasn't be loaded correctly or there are some issues with file permissions?

Comment: also check if there might be a plugin which needs to be updated on the url <jenkinsurl>/pluginManager. It appears that the plugin might not be compatible with the jenkins version?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have updated all the plugins which are getting showed in Plugin manager>>Updates, it shows empty now after update.

Can you help me with the plugin name which is not compatible so that I can look into it.

How to check the file permissions and plugins loaded correctly?

Comment: After all the plugin updates done in Updates tab of plugin manager still it shows the same error.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure regarding the compatibilty but I think it's the https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-support/ plugin. Here's the code for it: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-support-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/pickles/serialization/RiverWriter.java. Did you find any error while jenkins startup? Have you restarted it after the plugin updates? Maybe also try to stop the container completely and start a new one (not using docker restart). I had some strange behaviors in the past one time where that helped..